# javax.servlet.ServletException and The ResourceConfig Error

Tags: eclipse, rest, tomcat, jersey, jax-rs

I have a very simple HelloWorld JAX-RS application which is using jersey-servlet. Getting the above error, no matter howmuch I try I keep getting this error. I even corrected the package names in web.xml and refreshed the application after Maven Build in my eclipse and even exported the war and deployed manually, etc still not able to get thru this issue. Any kind help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance
ERROR - BEGIN
Error:HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

---

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-servlet] threw exception

---

Root Cause

---

com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.

---

ERROR - END
web.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"   
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"   
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  
 <servlet>  
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>  
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>  
    <init-param>  
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>  
        <param-value>com.javapoint.rest</param-value>  
    </init-param>  
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>  
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>  
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>  
  </servlet-mapping>  
</web-app>
```

---

Hello.java (for REST GET call)

---

```
package com.javapoint.rest;  
import javax.ws.rs.GET;  
import javax.ws.rs.Path;  
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  
@Path("/hello")  
public class Hello {  
  // This method is called if HTML and XML is not requested  
  @GET  
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)  
  public String sayPlainTextHello() {  
    return "Hello Jersey Plain";  
  }  
  // This method is called if XML is requested  
  @GET  
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)  
  public String sayXMLHello() {  
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Jersey" + "</hello>";  
  }  
  
  // This method is called if HTML is requested  
  @GET  
  @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)  
  public String sayHtmlHello() {  
    return "<html> " + "<title>" + "Hello Jersey" + "</title>"  
        + "<body><h1>" + "Hello Jersey HTML" + "</h1></body>" + "</html> ";  
  }  
}
```

Comment: Which server runtime and version is this happening in? Which version of Jersey is it? As this is built with Maven, what's in the POM file?

Comment: @nitind Thanks for the response. I am getting a different error now. But not with the same code. Rightnow I switched to a different example exactly given here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/restful_first_application.htm. As per the tutorial I have downloaded jaxrs-ri-2.17.zip and followed the steps exactly mentioned in the tutorialspoint.com example. My java version is jdk1.8.0_351 and I am using Tomcat =>apache-tomcat-8.5.91. Currently I am not using Maven , I am just building the war file in Eclipse (version  2020-12 (4.18.0)) and deploing the war file into tomcat webapps folder.

Comment: @nitind : Once I started tomcat, I am trying this rest url in postman: http://localhost:8080/UserManagement/rest/UserService/users. But I endup getting this error ************************** HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [Jersey RESTful Application] threw exception

Comment: Root Cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
  (ClassReader.java:153)
 jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.<init> org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.scanning.AnnotationAcceptingListener.process(AnnotationAcceptingListener.java:170) org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.scanClasses(ResourceConfig.java:899)
org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1190)
 org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$RuntimeConfig.<init>(ResourceConfig.java:1162). Thanks

Comment: Given that your Jersey version is so *old*, it may not support classes compiled for Java 1.8. Try a newer Jersey 2.x.

Comment: You are mixing Jersey 1 (com.sun.jersey) and Jersey 2 (org.glassfish.jersey). That would never work.